# Empty lines appear in HTML with Thymeleaf <th:remove> tag

Tags: java, thymeleaf

While working with **Thymeleaf** I have found out, that `th:remove` tag doesn't remove an items completely. In my example I'm iterating through the list of some objects and getting their properties:

Here is Thymeleaf code:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li th:each="category : ${dish.categories}">
        <a href="#" th:text="${category.name}">Category #</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

That renders the following HTML:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
</ol>
```

But when I use `th:remove` tag, an empty lines render instead of that removed element. Each `th:remove` tag generates every new line:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li th:each="category : ${dish.categories}">
        <a href="#" th:text="${category.name}">Category #</a>
    </li>
    <li th:remove="all"><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
    <li th:remove="all"><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
</ol>
```

will render the result:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
</ol>
```

**Is it possible to use `<th:remove>` without generating these empty lines?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**. `<th:remove>` will always leave empty lines.

This ability to remove the whitespace that is left behind has been requested on the thymeleaf issue tracker, https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/108

The feature request was declined and is therefore not available in the thymeleaf core. Perhaps someone will implement it as an "extra" (custom dialect). Here's a quote from that issue.

> Thymeleaf 3.0 now includes a Post-Processor API (see #400 and #401). A whitespace-collapsing utility looks like the perfect use case for a post-processor, provided by a custom dialect.
>
> Will close this as declined, as I don't think it should be a part of the core or the Standard Dialects.

Comment: Thanks for respond! There is also a workaround described there using custom `ITemplateWriter`.